# Constrain protocol usage to two class types

Tags: ios, swift

I have a protocol that I want to add a class constraint to, well I want it constrained to one of two classes actually, either a `UIView` or a `UIViewController`, but I can't get it to work. I've tried:

```
protocol MyProtocol where Self: UIView | UIViewController
```

```
protocol MyProtocol where Self: UIView, UIViewController
```

```
protocol MyProtocol: UIView, UIViewController
```

But I can't get it to work. Is this possible or am I just wasting my time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UIView** and **UIViewController** are class and both Objective-C and Swift don't support multiple inheritance from a class.

So, it will give you multiple inheritance error:

```
protocol MyProtocol: UIView, UIViewController
```

If you see something like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, PKCanvasViewDelegate, PKToolPickerObserver
```

This class is inheriting one class and conforming two protocols. The point is Swift only support single inheritance from a class.